# Memory leak with a lot of big images in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsarray

I'm trying to store **UIImage** datas in **NSArray**, actually 60 images, each with size of 300kb. Then, I'm trying to animate that images in **UIImageView**. 
My code:

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<61; ++i) {
        [arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", i]]];
    }

    img.animationImages = arr;
    img.animationDuration = 1.5;
    img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
    [img startAnimating];
```

When I test it in iPad Simulator 4.3, it works fine.
When I want to test it on my device (iPad 1), application **crashes**.
**Note:** App does not crashes if I comment this code: **[img startAnimating];**
**1. What could be the problem? I think it is memory problem...?!

2. Can I store a loooots of UIImages in NSArray?**

Comment: First try logging your app with Instruments to see numerically how much memory it uses. Don't forget to respond to low-memory warnings. Then see if you can reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: Ooo my God, memory used is 131mb!(

Comment: And the iPad has 256MB. Between the system using memory and your app you have to cede some (lots) of ground.

Comment: Note that a UIImage is stored uncompressed - so the file size of the (compressed) PNG files are irrelevant. A rough estimate on the memory size needed per picture is width x height x 4.

Comment: Note: App does not crashes if I comment this code: [img startAnimating];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your png files may have 300KB, but this is a compressing format.

To get an idea of the size of the Image itself you should multiply the width, height and bytes per pixel.

i.e. If an image has the size 1024 * 1024 and RGBA model, the images itself has an size of 4MB in the memory. And this is just one image. If you have 300 it is about 120MB.

Note: this is only a rough rule of thumb, but it gives you an idea.

So you should keep path-names in the array and load the image only if need, and thumbnails should be resized and stored on the disk as files. Do not just scale the UIImageView.

Here's [a great article](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) with code about resizing.

Comment: Can you show me example code, how to change UIImage quality using UIImage-Resize?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use that resize category of UIImage

Comment: its easy: copy the source files to your project, import the .h where needed, and use it like `UIImage *newImage = [oldImage resizedImage:CGSizeMake(30.0,30.0) interpolationQuality:   kCGInterpolationHigh];` Make sure to add the CoreGraphics framework.

Comment: What you mean saying: "Do not just scale the UIImageView.", how should I use startAnimating method of UIImageView?

Comment: I mean: don't post a giant image into a UIImageView and scale that View down to the size u really need. because this won't reduce the memory the image needs. For startAnimating you'll have to put images into animationImages, define the parameter animatingDuration and animationRepeatcount and call startAnimating.

Comment: ok. I'm not scaling UIImageView, it has same size as my images. Anyway, i tried your code, I get this error: `cgcontextsetinterpolationquality invalid context 0x0` Any idea?

Comment: see the comments http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

I solved the app crash problem with alternative way: I tried to use simple **NSTimer**. For each iteration I set n'th image to **UIImageView**:

- I have **UIImageView** in xib file, pointing to **img** variable.

> ```
> NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03 
>                             target:self 
>                             selector:@selector(tiktak) 
>                             userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
> int n = 0;
>
> -(void)tiktak {
>     n++;
>     img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
>                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blue Menu_%i.png", n]];
>     if(nn == 60) nn = 0;
> }
> ```

Animation is amazing. I've also tested it in Activity Monitor, CPU usage is 6% and less.

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise you store that many UIImages in an NSArray, its way too heavy and inefficient. From where are these images from (bundle, internet, device's gallery)?

Edit: I don't know how you want it to look, but you can build the array with the names of the UIImages, and then load the UIImage and show it. Like this:

```
for(i=0;i<60;i++){
 NSString *nameOfPicture=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture_%d",i+1]
 [array addObject:nameOfPicture];
}
```