# Maximum Width For UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage

Does anyone know if there is a maximum width for a UIImage? I am using [this](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/ParallaxBackground) framework on Github to create a parallax scrolling background.

I noticed that when I created an image with a width of 2000px and then created the @2x and @3x versions on some devices the image will appear as black but If I then shrink the image to a smaller width it shows up fine.

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: r u testing on ipad/iphone ? IF you are displaying image of such a huge size, you need to take care of displaying it properly by scaling it, else anypart of the image could be loaded on the screen.

Comment: 2000px is not a metric that tells us anything about it's memory consumption. if it is easily to compress and render content, this doesn't sound much. if it is an image with many details even a much smaller images could be too much.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, compression only matters for saving to disk. When you display an image to screen it has to be uncompressed into memory. The memory footprint is h*w*bytes_per_pixel (3, or 4 if it has an alpha channel). Older devices (iPhone 4s) can choke on large images due to lack of memory.

Comment: it matters for decompression, as this eats up memory.

Comment: how to estimate images sizes in memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229346/memory-leak-with-a-lot-of-big-images-in-ipad/8229849#8229849

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be device dependent based on memory availability. If you want to use really large images, say, for the background of a game, I would suggest you break them up into tiles and piece them together in the game, ideally recycling cells so that only the images you are currently displaying are in memory.